# async_write only sends after the server is closed

Tags: c++, networking, c++17, boost-asio, asio

I'm trying to send messages via async_write, but they are only sent after I shutdown the server ( ctrl-c)

For example:
as client I send "test" and "test2", and only after closing the server client recieves "testtest2"

I'm making a chat that accepts a message from a user (successfully) and has to broadcast it to everyone

message sending code

```
void Server::writeHandler(int id, boost::system::error_code error){
    if (!error){
        std::cout << "[DEBUG] message broadcasted ";
    } else {
        close_connection(id);
    }
}
void Server::broadcast(std::string msg, boost::system::error_code error){
    for (auto& user : m_users){ // for every user in unordered map of users
        asio::async_write(user.second->socket, asio::buffer(msg, msg.size()),
            std::bind(&Server::writeHandler, this, user.first, std::placeholders::_1));
    }
}
```

broadcast calls in onMessage

```
void Server::onMessage(int id, boost::system::error_code error){
    if (!error){
        broadcast(m_read_msg, error); // char m_read_msg[PACK_SIZE] // PACK_SIZE = 512
        asio::async_read(m_users[id].get()->socket, asio::buffer(m_read_msg, PACK_SIZE), // PACK_SIZE = 512
            std::bind(&Server::onMessage, this, id, std::placeholders::_1));
    } else {
        close_connection(id);
    }
}
```

server run function:

```
void Server::run(int port){
    asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint(asio::ip::tcp::v4(), port);
    std::cout << "[DEBUG] binded on " << port << std::endl;

    // acceptor initialization
    m_acceptor = std::make_shared<asio::ip::tcp::acceptor>(m_io, endpoint);
    
    // start to listen for connections
    listen();

    // run the io_service in thread
    io_thread = std::thread( [&]{ m_io.run(); } ); // m_io = io_serivce

    while (true){
    }
}

void Server::listen(){
    std::shared_ptr<User> pUser(new User(m_io));
    m_acceptor->async_accept(pUser->socket, std::bind(&Server::onAccept, this, pUser));
}
```

Comment: Please include minimal, self-contained code. In particular I can tell that your error is that `io_context::run` (or that family) is being run too late, but you left that part out of the question, so we can't help you.

Comment: @sehe I added a function through which the server is runs, I hope this helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Infinite loops are [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in C++.

Your `std::string msg` is a local (parameter) and passing it to an async operation (`async_write`) is also UB.

To start a thread, immediately followed by an infinite loop is useless, unless the objective is to waste a lot of CPU power. So, replace it with just

```
 m_io.run();
```

Next up, the code is far from self contained and lacks all manner of error handling. Here's my imaged minimal completion, fixing the UBs already mentioned:

```cpp
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using asio::ip::tcp;
using boost::system::error_code;
using namespace std::placeholders;

struct User {
    User(asio::io_service& io) : socket(io) {}

    tcp::socket socket;
};

struct Server {
    void run(uint16_t port) {
        m_acceptor = {m_io, {{}, port}};
        std::cout << "[DEBUG] bound on " << port << std::endl;

        listen();

        m_io.run();
    }

    void close_connection(int) {}
    std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<User>> m_users;

    void writeHandler(int id, error_code error, std::shared_ptr<void>) {
        if (!error) {
            std::cout << "[DEBUG] message broadcasted ";
        } else {
            close_connection(id);
        }
    }

    void broadcast(std::string msg, boost::system::error_code /*error*/) {
        for (auto& [id, usr] : m_users) { // for every user in unordered map of users
            asio::async_write(usr->socket, asio::buffer(*shared_msg),
                              bind(&Server::writeHandler, this, id, _1, shared_msg));
        }
    }

    void listen() {
        std::shared_ptr<User> pUser(new User(m_io));
        m_acceptor.async_accept(pUser->socket, std::bind(&Server::onAccept, this, pUser));
    }

    void onAccept(std::shared_ptr<User> /*user*/) { listen(); }

    asio::io_service m_io;
    tcp::acceptor    m_acceptor{m_io};
};

int main() {
    Server s;
    s.run(8989);
}
```

Note that nothing ever broadcasts in the first place, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

What I *can* see is that

- `io_service` is deprecated (use `io_context`)
- passing `io_service&` around is anti-pattern (use executors)
- you dearly need to separate the concerns for `Server` and `User`. The handlers for each user session need to use the state from `User` and are much more naturally member of `User`. In fact, that's the only way to do it correctly because with a out-of-session broadcast you MUST guarantee the correct sequencing of writes, which means you MUST have a per-session (user) queue
- close_connection is antipattern (IO is external "reality", you follow it, instead of the way around). Instead use `enable_shared_from_this`
- When you do, make `m_users` store a `weak_ptr` so you can observe when connections terminate

Here's what it would look like with those addressed:

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/46be24e9f52e06de)**

```cpp
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using asio::ip::tcp;
using boost::system::error_code;
using namespace std::placeholders;

using Message = std::string;

struct UserSession : std::enable_shared_from_this<UserSession> {
    UserSession(tcp::socket s, int /*id*/) : socket_(std::move(s)) {
        std::cout << "New UserSession from " << ep_ << std::endl;
    }
    ~UserSession() {
        std::cout << "Closed UserSession from " << ep_ << std::endl;
    }

    void start() {
        read_loop();
    }

    void send(Message msg) {
        outbox_.push_back(std::move(msg));
        if (outbox_.size()==1)
            write_loop();
    }

  private:
    tcp::socket         socket_;
    tcp::endpoint       ep_; // cache for use after socket_ becomes invalid
    Message             incoming_;
    std::deque<Message> outbox_;

    void read_loop() {
        async_read(socket_, asio::dynamic_buffer(incoming_),
                   [this, self = shared_from_this()](error_code ec, size_t) {
                       if (!ec) {
                           // TODO
                           read_loop();
                       }
                   });
    }

    void write_loop() { 
        if (outbox_.empty())
            return;
        async_write(socket_, asio::buffer(outbox_.front()),
                    [this, self = shared_from_this()](error_code ec, size_t) {
                        if (!ec) {
                            outbox_.pop_front();
                            write_loop();
                        }
                    });
    }
};

using Handle = std::weak_ptr<UserSession>;

struct Server {
    explicit Server(asio::any_io_executor ex, uint16_t port) : m_acceptor{ex, {{}, port}} {
        std::cout << "[DEBUG] bound on " << m_acceptor.local_endpoint() << std::endl;
    }

    void listen() { accept_loop(); }

    void broadcast(Message msg) {
        auto shared_msg = std::make_shared<Message>(std::move(msg));
        for (auto& [id, handle] : m_users) // for every user in unordered map of users
            if (auto usr = handle.lock())
                usr->send(msg);
    }

  private:
    int next_user_id = 0;
    std::map<int, Handle> m_users;

    void accept_loop() {
        m_acceptor.async_accept([this](error_code ec, tcp::socket s) {
            if (!ec) {
                auto id  = next_user_id++;
                auto usr = std::make_shared<UserSession>(std::move(s), id);
                m_users.emplace(id, usr);
                usr->start();

                accept_loop();
            }
        });
    }

    tcp::acceptor m_acceptor;
};

int main() {
    asio::io_context ioc;

    Server s(ioc.get_executor(), 8989);
    s.listen();

    ioc.run();
}
```

Local demo:

[image]

### BONUS: Chat Server?

Of course, still nothing ever calls `broadcast`. Assuming you might actually want something like a chat-server:

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b8e1fdfd332017ea)**

```cpp
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using asio::ip::tcp;
using boost::system::error_code;
using namespace std::placeholders;

using Id = int;

struct Message {
    Id          sender;
    std::string text;
};

struct IServer {
    virtual ~IServer() = default;
    virtual void broadcast(Message msg) = 0;
};

struct UserSession : std::enable_shared_from_this<UserSession> {
    UserSession(tcp::socket s, Id id, IServer& srv) : socket_(std::move(s)), id_(id), svr_(srv) {
        std::cout << "New UserSession from " << ep_ << std::endl;
    }
    ~UserSession() {
        std::cout << "Closed UserSession from " << ep_ << std::endl;
    }

    void start() {
        read_loop();
    }

    void send(Message msg) {
        outbox_.push_back(std::move(msg));
        if (outbox_.size()==1)
            write_loop();
    }

    Id get_id() const { return id_; }

  private:
    tcp::socket         socket_;
    Id                  id_;
    IServer&            svr_;
    tcp::endpoint       ep_; // cache for use after socket_ becomes invalid
    Message             incoming_;
    std::deque<Message> outbox_;

    void read_loop() {
        incoming_.sender = id_;
        async_read_until( //
            socket_, asio::dynamic_buffer(incoming_.text), "\n",
            [this, self = shared_from_this()](error_code ec, size_t n) {
                std::cout << ep_ << ": Read " << ec.message() << "\n";
                if (!ec) {
                    svr_.broadcast(std::move(incoming_));
                    incoming_.text.erase(0, n);
                    read_loop();
                }
            });
    }

    void write_loop() { 
        if (outbox_.empty())
            return;
        async_write(socket_, asio::buffer(outbox_.front().text),
                    [this, self = shared_from_this()](error_code ec, size_t) {
                        if (!ec) {
                            outbox_.pop_front();
                            write_loop();
                        }
                    });
    }
};

using Handle = std::weak_ptr<UserSession>;

struct Server : IServer {
    explicit Server(asio::any_io_executor ex, uint16_t port) : m_acceptor{ex, {{}, port}} {
        std::cout << "[DEBUG] bound on " << m_acceptor.local_endpoint() << std::endl;
    }

    void listen() { accept_loop(); }

    virtual void broadcast(Message msg) override {
        m_history.push_back(msg);
        while (m_history.size() > MAX_HIST)
            m_history.pop_front();

        for (auto& [id, handle] : m_users) // for every user in unordered map of users
            if (auto usr = handle.lock())
                if (usr->get_id() != msg.sender)
                    usr->send(msg);
    }

  private:
    Id                   next_user_id = 0;
    std::map<Id, Handle> m_users;
    static size_t constexpr MAX_HIST = 100;
    std::deque<Message>  m_history;

    void accept_loop() {
        m_acceptor.async_accept([this](error_code ec, tcp::socket s) {
            if (!ec) {
                erase_if(m_users, [](auto& pair) { return pair.second.expired(); }); // garbage collect

                auto id  = next_user_id++;
                auto usr = std::make_shared<UserSession>(std::move(s), id, *this);
                m_users.emplace(id, usr);

                for (auto& msg : m_history)
                    usr->send(msg);
                broadcast({-1, "** Now " + std::to_string(m_users.size()) + " users online **\n"});
                usr->start();

                accept_loop();
            }
        });
    }

    tcp::acceptor m_acceptor;
};

int main() {
    asio::io_context ioc;

    Server s(ioc.get_executor(), 8989);
    s.listen();

    ioc.run();
}
```

With a local demo again:

[image]

Comment: Note that the above took 20 minutes, and was mainly to make the code self-contained. Your question should ideally contain that code from the start. Of course, now I have my diagnosis, and will show you my fixed up solution in a bit.

Comment: Took longer than half an hour, but now I made it much more complete. Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you so much not only for your help, but also for providing examples and even a whole working server, I really appreciate it. I apologize for the stupid mistakes, I'm just starting to program in C++ and with this, being my second project, your help and notes is really appreciated.